# ¿Cómo crear un entorno de python en VS code?

Tags: python, vscode, virtualenv

He intentado crear un entorno en Visual Studio Code y ya instalé el virtualenv, pero aun así no me genera el entorno:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he intentado de todo, pero no se me crea el entorno.

Comment: Te está diciendo que no encuentra `virtualenv` y no es problema de visual code. ¿Puedes añadir a la pregunta cómo instalaste virtualenv? Una alternativa es usar el módulo `venv` estándar, algo así: `python -m venv .venv`. En la [documentación](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_creating-environments) se explica cómo activar los entornos virtuales en visual code.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, con el comando python -m venv .venv se pudo solucionar. Gracias nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

El error al parecer es que lo estabas intentando desde una venta de PowerShell. Escoje una ventana de CommandPrompt y con eso seguro se soluciona. Para ello da click en la cruz junto a la etiqueta powershell, donde podrás cambiar de ventana.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).